# How to send JSON to MVC API (using Ajax Post)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to post some data using Ajax, but it is not getting through when using content type of application/json (*HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable*), however if I change the content type to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' then it does work.

Any ideas?

Ajax code extract:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {"hello":"test"},
    url: "http://workingUrl/controller",
    contentType : 'application/json',
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    .....
```

Web API 2:

```
   public IHttpActionResult Post(testModel hello)
    {
      /// do something here
    }
```

Model:

```
    public class testModel
    {
        public string hello {get;set;}

        public testModel()
        { }
    }
```

Fiddler:

```
   HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable (In the IDE, I have a breakpoint in the Post method which is not hit).
```

I have tried adding a formatter to WebAPi.config, but no luck

```
 config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this **JSON.stringify(TestData)** as shown below -

```
var TestData = {
    "hello": "test"
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/values",
    data: JSON.stringify(TestData),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    processData: true,
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(jqXHR);
        alert("success..." + data);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Output -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've never specified contentType when I've done this and it's always works.  However, if it works when you use 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' then what's the problem?

I do see a couple thing off in your ajax.  I would do this

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
data: {hello:"test"},
url: "http://workingUrl/controller/Post",
cache: false)}
```

For data, maybe quotes around the variable name will work but I've never had them there.

Next, the url in the ajax call doesn't have the name of your controller action.  That needs to be in there.